Do I need to get a visa (Schengen) for transit?
I'm flying to Belgium on a short-term tourist visa for a sport competition. But Belgium will not be the city of entry. I'm citizen of Kazakhstan but I realized that it would be cheaper for me to travel through Russia. Will Estonia, Latvia or Lithuania let me through as transit cities if I have paid plane tickets and a paid hotel in my hands?

Please add what visas you currently have and what is your intended travel route. As of now, the question is unclear.

I’m surprised. There are no flights or trains between Russia and any EU or Schengen country, are there?

No, there are still working checkpoints on the border between the Russian Federation and the EU.

The Schengen visa application is handled by the main destination of your visit. When you are doing simply tourism, that is the country with the most days, but when the goal of your visit is a sports competition, it is surely that country even if you do not spend the most days there. Unless there are special annotations in your visa, you can travel through other Schengen countries on the way to your main destination.
In your visa application, you describe your trip. If traveling through the Baltics was mentioned in your letter, and if the visa was granted, then you can travel through those countries. (But keep in mind that Russia is under sanctions for starting a war of aggression against Ukraine. Getting from Russia to the EU can be difficult, and it can become more difficult if sanctions are strengthened.)
It is allowed to adjust travel plans after the visa was granted as long as the main destination and purpose stay the same, but it is not allowed to misrepresent the plans during the application. To avoid misunderstandings, it may be best to stick to the plans from your application.
